# Google maps destination SwiftUI

Tags: google-maps, swiftui, location

I am working on a project where users can add the addresses of their clients. I managed to make these addresses to be interactive so that when you tap on them a sheet shows the option to open either GoogleMaps or Apple Maps. However I am not sure how to set the specific address I tap to be the destination when the map opens. This is what I have:

```
    .actionSheet(isPresented: $showingSheet){
         
                    let latitude = 51.49
                    let longitude = -30
                             

         let appleURL = "http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=\(latitude),\(longitude)"
         let googleURL = "comgooglemaps://?daddr=\(latitude),\(longitude)&directionsmode=driving"
                    //let wazeURL = "waze://?ll=\(latitude),\(longitude)&navigate=false"
        
                    let googleItem = ("Google Map", URL(string:googleURL)!)
                    //let wazeItem = ("Waze", URL(string:wazeURL)!)
            var installedNavigationApps = [("Apple Maps", URL(string:appleURL)!)]
                            
                    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(googleItem.1) {
                        installedNavigationApps.append(googleItem)
                    }

//                    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(wazeItem.1) {
//                        installedNavigationApps.append(wazeItem)
//                    }
        
                    var buttons: [ActionSheet.Button] = []
                    for app in installedNavigationApps {
                        let button: ActionSheet.Button = .default(Text(app.0)) {
                            UIApplication.shared.open(app.1, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                        }
                        buttons.append(button)
                    }
                    let cancel: ActionSheet.Button = .cancel()
                    buttons.append(cancel)
                    
            return ActionSheet(title: Text("Navigate"), message: Text("Select an app..."), buttons: buttons)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Both Apple Maps and Google Maps have a similar URL scheme for opening their map for driving directions.

- Apple Maps reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html
- Google Maps URL scheme for iOS: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme#directions

In both cases, the `daddr` value you're passing can be sent a full address, which the Maps product will then geocode and pinpoint.

You're currently sending a stringified version of your lat/lng coordinates in that string, which each maps product can use to derive a location. But there neither scheme seems to support an option of "here are the coordinates I want to use, and this is the address I want to show" – it's one or the other.

So if you take the address you have and enter it as a single string (don't forget to URL encode it – you may find it easiest to assemble your URL using the [`URLComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents) and [`URLQueryItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlqueryitem) helper objects) you ought to be able to use that encoded string as a new `daddr` value.